# Explorer.exe memory leak while exhausting one CPU core since 10586.17

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, memory-leaks

Explorer.exe (GUI) is still working and responsive but one thread hangs at
`ntdll.dll!RtlAcquireSRWLockShared` with `ntdll.dll!ZwQueryFullAttributesFile` being on the top of the stack.

Memory is leaking while exhausting one CPU core. This seems to occur for me since 10586.17 (Win10 Pro x64 i7, 16GB)

2nd Question:Does it make sense to report it to MS? If yes, where exactly?

Comment: What makes you think you have a memory leak precisely?  Most memory leak problems that Windows users experience, (more the 99%) are caused by third-party drivers, so it makes no sense to report it to Microsoft.

Comment: explorer.exe constantly increases consuming paged mem. I did a dump from explorer.exe which is about 4gb. I could try to figure out the leak, if it hurts further...

Comment: Install the WPT (part of Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select First Level, CPU, VAlloc, Resident Set). After you captured 1-2 Minutes of the memory usage grow and CPU usage, stop the trace and save it into a ETL file. Now compress the large ETL + ngenpdb folder (IMPORTANT) into a Zip/RAR/7z (to reduce the upload size), upload it to OneDrive and post a share link here.

Comment: next time it occurs, i will. in the mean time I ran MS debug diagnostic tools over my 4gb dump, but with no results (at least obvious to me).

Comment: have you seen the issue again? Were you able to capture a trace?

Comment: no, not until now again....currently it's hard to get to know what MS is changing when they release their patches since TH2. But I did sth. very similar with PerfView.exe (I guess comparable with WPRUI) when it first occured... that .etl+.etlx File is about 12 MB compressed, but I dont' want post a public link, as I don't know, what private things it captured

Comment: @magicandre1981 The result of my examination is posted in the question. I do not believe in managed code being culprit, as you mentioned ngenpdb

Comment: I'll prepare it with a newly happened dump of a blue screen (never did with Win8.1 and TH1 afaik). There are some hints pointing to some trouble while indexing or opening large video files over SMB2....

Comment: Have you uploaded the files? I haven't got any email.

Comment: @magicandre1981 very kind of you. but very probably the error was caused by a faulty net work share and NAS hardware beginning to downgrade. the hint with WPRUI was very helpful. it pointed me to the network issue. Though I will prepare the upload.

Comment: I posted what I saw

Comment: you should disable generating previews /thumbnails in the Explorer options to workaround it. The memory data are not really included in the trace, but loading the video metadata seams to cause the memory usage next to the CPU usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU usage comes indirectly from network. The real cause is Exploer tries to generate tooltips from Video file (`shell32.dll!CInfoTip::GetInfoTip`). This causes the `mfmpeg2srcsnk.dll` (Media Foundation MPEG2 Source and Sink DLL) to do work to get the data (`KernelBase.dll!GetFileAttributesExW`). This causes CPU usage in the network components of Windows (mup.sys!MupCleanup, `rdbss.sys`!RxCommonCleanup and laetr rom the kernel: `ntoskrnl.exe!CcFlushCache, ntoskrnl.exe!MmFlushSection, ntoskrnl.exe!MiFlushSectionInternal`):

[image]

[image]

So the cleanup after reading causes the CPU usage.

Comment: great. even narrowing it down to tool tips. Did you see a reason for the blue screen? would you consider the tool tip "hang" as sort of a bug and report it to MS?

Comment: the crash is unrelated to this issue. You get a "A critical system process died" eror. Some processes are required in Windows and so they are flagged as critical. And when a critical process is closed, Windows creates a bugcheck and halts Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560358(v=vs.85).aspx